# Running ductwork through unused chimney

Tags: hvac, attic, chimney

The chimney in our house has been unused for years since there is no fireplace and the high efficiency units we have vent out the side of the house. We recently had the chimney removed down to the roofline since that portion was in such poor shape.

The attic of our house is fully finished but has no heating or cooling. I'm considering running a flexible duct down the (unused) chimney to tie into the ductwork in the basement. I have easy access to the open chimney in the attic since there's already an access panel. There's also already a hole cut into the chimney at the bottom that was used for the old water heater.

I'm wondering if it really is as simple as dropping some flex duct down from the attic and connecting both ends. I've heard that running ductwork through chimneys is against code in some areas because it's highly dangerous. However, I'm assuming this refers to chimneys which are actively in use. Currently our chimney is nothing more than a brick tube taking up space.

Comment: Sounds like you're thinking to use the chimney duct for HVAC-ing your attic?  I don't know about legality, but since your chimney is unlikely to be insulated, that may be a consideration.  Also, how would you handle return air in the attic?

Comment: How big is it, and how clean is it? On the whole, if you can stand taking it down more, the space it took up used as a chase would be better than running a duct (especially a flex duct, which are highly restrictive .vs. a smooth rigid duct) down it, given all the space the bricks take up. But that may not be practical if it's being used as a structural support for part of the house.

Comment: @Huesmann The chimney is fully inside the walls of the house, so I don't think insulation is a concern. I am worried about an air return, but I was at least considering not having one.

Comment: @Ecnerwal It's maybe a couple feet across. I'd love to take it down, but aside from the basement and a small access in the attic, none of it is exposed, so it would mean tearing apart walls on multiple floors of the house which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: If  it's a couple of feet across, you can take it down from the attic end through its own hole. I'd want to at least take it down from roofline to attic floor and get rid of that taking up space in the attic.  If it's tolerably clean and the hole is big enough, you can run a duct up and return air down around it, with a second hole at the bottom (should be a cleanout door as well as the flue entry) but insulated duct would be better in that case.

Comment: It might be better (though slightly more difficult) to run rigid duct down the chimney instead of flex. As you've noted, using an old chimney for other purposes _might_ be a code violation in some areas. Since we don't know where you are, and questions of local code are off-topic, your best bet would be to call the local building commission/inspector's office and ask them if this is legal in your area.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Good point that the remainder of the chimney space could potentially function as an air return. I'm not sure how clean it is since I haven't actually looked down the chimney, but that's worth checking out. I wonder how to actually allow airflow down there though since the wall would be closed off.

Comment: Any chance you could take the chimney out? That's what the previous owners of our 1907 house did to get duct space for the upstairs.

Comment: So do you still have a (unused) fireplace?

Comment: @KMJ It's not impossible, but it's too much work to make it worthwhile.

Comment: @Huesmann No fireplace at all, unused or otherwise that I'm aware of. The house is over 100 years old and the chimney passes through the kitchen so I wouldn't be surprised if it was used for a cooking fire at some point, but it's closed in the wall now.

Comment: So what's supporting the chimney?  Or is the (ex-) fireplace walled up and there's some unused space?

Comment: @Huesmann The chimney extends all the way to the basement floor. I'm sure there's some other support on the length of it, but since it's walled it, I'm not sure how specifically.